# How export Amazon EC2 Spot price history

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I know Amazon's spot price history tool. How can I export the historical prices e.g. to csv. Is there any possibility to get the raw data?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the aws cli to get the data in json format, for example:

```
aws ec2 describe-spot-price-history  --start-time 2017-01-06T07:08:09 --end-time 2017-01-07T08:09:10
```

Another way would be to use the REST API with `DescribeSpotPriceHistory`.
For example, to get all the values for 12/01/18:

```
https://ec2.amazonaws.com/?Action=DescribeSpotPriceHistory &StartTime=2018-12-01T00:00:00.000Z &EndTime=2018-12-01T23:59:59.000Z &AUTHPARAMS
```